# Unevaluated operands and auto return type

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, decltype

According with [[5/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#8) and [[7.1.7.2/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.type.simple-4) (working draft):

- The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an *unevaluated operand*
- An *unevaluated operand* is not evaluated

Consider the code below:

```
#include<type_traits>

struct S { using type = int; };

int f(int i);

template<typename T>
typename T::type g(T);

template<typename T>
auto h(T v) { return v; }

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f(42)), int>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(g(S{})), int>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(h(42)), int>::value, "!");
}
```

It goes without saying that `f` and `g` are not evaluated actually.
On the other side, the function `h` has an `auto` return type that is deduced from its body, thus from its arguments and thus from the deduced type `T`.

Can it still be considered an *unevaluated operand* in this case?
I mean, it seems to me that, in the context of the `decltype`, the function `h` *must* be evaluated to know what the actual return type is.

For I'm quite sure that the working draft is right, the question is: what's wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: One way to look at this would be: Does the compiler need to know what value `v` is to be able to deduce `T` from `h(42)`, or just what type `v` is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to determine the type denoted by `decltype(h(42))`, the compiler needs to perform template argument deduction for `h` and instantiate the template specialization `h<int>` to examine its body and determine the return type. This is *not* the same as evaluating `h(42)`; for example, if `h` contained any side effects such as printing a message, those side effects would not occur.

Comment: Your answer made me feel quite stupid! :-) ... When speaking about functions, I've ever thought of _unevaluated operands_ as _something that doesn't require a definition_. Actually, the key part is that they are _unevaluated_, even in the case in the example. It makes sense once explained this way. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Can it still be considered an unevaluated operand in this case? I
>   mean, it seems to me that, in the context of the decltype, the
>   function h must be evaluated to know what the actual return type is.

It's still an Unevaluated context. As [Brain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39028375/1621391)(which is the shorter answer) explains.

The C++ standard talks about template argument deduction process, and in substituting arguments for function templates:
[[temp.deduct/7]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#7) *(emphasis mine)*:

> The substitution occurs in all types and expressions that are used in
>   the function type and in template parameter declarations. The
>   expressions include not only constant expressions such as those that
>   appear in array bounds or as nontype template arguments **but also
>   general expressions (i.e., non-constant expressions) inside `sizeof`,
>   `decltype`, and other contexts that allow non-constant expressions.** The
>   substitution proceeds in lexical order and stops when a condition that
>   causes deduction to fail is encountered.

You can start reading from [the first paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct) to get more detailed info about template argument deduction.

---

### If you are interested, we can follow the short story

*(Note: All quoted paragraphs are partially reproduced, click the section links to see the full paragraph)*:

Since you already know about `decltype` and *unevaluated contexts*, and have quoted relevant sections, we can skip those and start with `auto`...

> **[[dcl.spec.auto/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#1):** The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` type-specifiers are used to designate a
>   **placeholder type** that will be replaced later by deduction from an
>   initializer....

A view from ***placeholder types***:

> **[[dcl.spec.auto/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#2):** The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator...
>   ...
>   If the declared return type of the function contains a **placeholder
>   type**, the return type of the function is deduced from non-discarded
>   `return` statements, if any, in the body of the function

About **placeholder type deduction**:

> **[[dcl.type.auto.deduct/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-1):**
>   **Placeholder type deduction** is the process by which a type containing a
>   placeholder type is replaced by a deduced type.

Deducing **placeholder** return types:

> **[[type.auto.deduct/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-4):**
>   If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type `T'`
>   replacing `T` is determined using the rules for **template argument
>   deduction**

*If the story isn't very clear, you may want to read the entire sections for each quoted paragraph.*